# Sharepoint 2010 OfficialFileUrl is Always NULL

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, shared-libraries

I am trying to Get the **RecordCenterURL** from **Sharepoint2010**,

I have created Connection to Connect RecordCenter or DocumentRepository. I used this LINK

When I try to Retrieve the OfficialFileUrl from Application, Its always return NULL value.

I have used this sample Code , Please help me for this Issue.

```
string URL = "http://inblr-iifw8sv03:31521";

                SPSite site = new SPSite(URL);
                string recordCenterUrl = string.Empty;

                if (site.WebApplication.OfficialFileUrl != null)// This is Always NULL
                {
                    recordCenterUrl = site.WebApplication.OfficialFileUrl.ToString().
                        Replace("_vti_bin/officialfile.asmx", string.Empty);
                }

                Console.WriteLine("URL Found " + recordCenterUrl);
                Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the Send To Recordcenter showing up in the site collection when you choose "Send to" context menu on e.g. document? Please double check General Settings -> Configure Send to Connections (in Central Admin), perhaps you configured it for wrong webapplication?

Comment: No I did it for the Same Application.. Still I am getting the same Response.